# Using Manifoldjs with windows 10 10122 - has anyone got the app to show up?

Tags: windows-10, manifoldjs

Using manifoldjs on a windows 10 box - tried to use a simplistic site such as www.google.com or even www.nick.com which is the demo used in Build 2015.

The app can install correctly with powershell and I am able to start the app but all I get is a blank screen and then in say 30 seconds the app quits.

Anyone had any success with the Hosted Web Apps in windows 10?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older post but I just came across it.  it sounds like the generator was using a different version of the manifest than what you build was on.  We tried to stay with the most recent versions of each of the Insider releases.
  The good news is we think we are on the final one now, and I'm guessing you are on a newer build as well.  Head over to the issue log: https://github.com/manifoldjs/ManifoldJS/issues or post a reply here if it's still not working for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are specifically looking to get a hosted web app working we do have a yo generator that gets one up and running.

https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/generator-appx

Install yo generator

```
npm i -g gulp yo generator-appx
```

Create yo project

```
yo appx
```

To install a Windows 10 hosted app (Must be on Windows 10 of course, your build 10122 should work fine)

```
gulp appx:dev
```

I think someone from the ManifoldJS team will respond as well.

There is probably an error logged in Microsoft-Windows-AppHost. You may have to enable the diagnostics tracing by right-clicking on the log and choosing the option to enable tracing.